# Enable my-own AutoPlugin

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I run my sbt-plugin from a repository after it works from a relative `dependsOn(...)` path?

## Background

I made an AutoPlugin [following mukis.de's instructions](http://mukis.de/pages/sbt-autoplugins-tutorial/) with no problems

I published said plugin to my own Maven repository (no problems or warnings)

I can use `addSbtPlugin` in my `project/plugins.sbt` (again - no problems or warnings)

**BUT** I can't `enablePlugins(MyPlugin)` in `build.sbt`
I receive the message

`... build.sbt:5: error: not found: value MyPlugin`

## Links

Link to [failing-version with maven repositories](https://bitbucket.org/g-pechorin/samon2/src/a5c8b1f44dc7e7311afc98eee7c35f5be053bbe6/hosted-demo.samon/?at=default)

Link to [working-version with relative paths](https://bitbucket.org/g-pechorin/samon2/src/a5c8b1f44dc7e7311afc98eee7c35f5be053bbe6/relative-demo.samon/?at=default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now tried it on two different computers. I had an old not-a-plugin copy on my computer which didn't have any tasks / plugin / whatnot in it

I tried `clean` `update` and `reload plugins` commands before noticing that `~/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13` wasn't being changed

"Works for me" on all three computers

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a missing import. Did you make sure to import the class in the build.sbt file?

Comment: Yes - just caused a "class not found" error. (... and then I tried it again on my lunch break and realized what was wrong)